# How to write xml within an xml element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to write xml within an xml element using XSLT.

Since im already within an element im unable to use match template function. I am trying to use xsl copy of but it results in the following error

***an item of type 'element' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'attribute'***

**XML Format pre Transformation**

```
<Results>
<Locations>
  <Location>
    <xyz>asa</xyz>
     <extended>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </extended>
     <another>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </another>
   </Location>
     <Location>
    <xyz>asa</xyz>
     <extended>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </extended>
     <another>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </another>
   </Location>
</Locations>
</Results>
```

** Desired XML Format After Transformation**

```
 <TransactionResponse ResponseType="Location_Query_Response1">

 <ParsedData Name="MessageData" Value="&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;*******************************Location*******"/>

  <Location>
    <xyz>asa</xyz>
     <extended>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </extended>
     <another>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </another>
   </Location>
     <Location>
    <xyz>asa</xyz>
     <extended>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </extended>
     <another>
        <abc>blah</abc>
     </another>
     </Location>

  </TransactionResponse>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="TransactionResponse">
         <xsl:element name="Data">
              <xsl:element name="ParsedData">
                    this piece works
               </xsl:element>

           <xsl:for-each select="Locations/Location/*>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Location"/>

           </xsl:for-each>

          </xsl:element>
   </xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another template to re-write *Locations*, avoiding `<xsl:for-each>` on all child nodes. Also, no need to use `<xsl:element>` as you can directly use node.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <TransactionResponse>
          <Data>
               <ParsedData>
                    this piece works
               </ParsedData>

               <xsl:apply-templates select="Locations"/>

          </Data>
   </TransactionResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Locations">
   <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```